# Why is this error connection database asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ado.net

Why is this error

> An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException'
>   occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user
>   code

When using this:

```
department data  = conn.dep_con.Single(x => x.depId == id);
```

web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DataBaseConn" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=companye;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is way to few details to find out what is happening. Please post some more code and show where the error is occurring.

Comment: This is a rather general error, you need to look at the inner exception which will provide more details

Comment: What are the details that you need I'm learning new

Comment: {"One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:\r\n\r\nServer.Models.department: : EntityType 'department' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.\r\ndep_con: EntityType: EntitySet 'dep_con' is based on type 'department' that has no keys defined.\r\n"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you have no data in your table for that current depId, try changing your code to this and see if it solves your issue.

```
department data  = conn.dep_con.SingleOrDefault(x => x.depId == id);
```